# How to bring one object with 3 attribute from a list or XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, list, listbox

I have a list of bookshop, after user selects one of the items from the listbox, it should show the price and related points to that Item:

```
book name1, 15$, 5 point
book name2, 25$, 15 point
book name3, 11$, 8 point
book name4, 30$, 12 point
```

at the end if he selects 2 of these books, the price should be calculated and also it should shows how many points did he collected.
I am not using database for now, I was thinking for a xml file for it, I do not know who to organize my xml file and how should read it after that. it also should have remove ability, it means if user inserts 3 different book name, but he wants to remove one of it, he should be able to select the name, and remove it and also the price and the point should be remove from the total text field.

Comment: You've specified a *lot* of tasks there. They're all separable. Which *exact* bit did you want help with? (I doubt that anyone's going to do all of them for you in one big answer...)

Comment: just for more info this should work in Windows CE and .Net frame work 3.5 is available.

Comment: thanks for the hint, then simply I need a XML structure and a reader for the above sample.

Answer (score 1):

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<books>  
<book>
<name>Book1</name>
<price>10</price>
<points>1</points>
</book>  
<book>
<name>Book2</name>
<price>20</price>
<points>10</points>
</book>
</books>
```

How to read it:
( i made a little helper class "Books", just to keep things clean, but you dont have to do this, you can use anonymous types aswell)

```
 public class Books
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public double price {get;set;}
            public int points { get; set; }
        }
```

read the xmlfile: (you have to import the `using System.Xml.Linq;` namespace for this)

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PathToYourXml.xml");
        List<Books> books = (from x in doc.Descendants("book")
                    select new Books
                    {   name = x.Element("name").Value,
                        price = Convert.ToDouble(x.Element("price").Value),
                        points = Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("points").Value)
                    }).ToList();
```

print out the results:

```
        foreach (Books i in books)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.name + " " + i.price + " " + i.points);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you it looks perfect, I have to run it on Windows CE, as soon as I start to use this part of the code :  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PathToYourXml.xml"); it crashes. (I have changed the path to correct file path)